# Create/Sort List<X> with values ordered the same as in List<Y>

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, java-8

I have a List of Objects `A`, which is used to retrieve another List of Objects `B`. But the second List is randomly sorted. Both Object types have the `id` property in common.

What I'm doing at the moment:

```
List<A> input = ...;
List<B> output = new ArrayList<>();
for(A a : input) {
    output.add(getOutputObjectById(a.getId()));
}
```

The problem is, that `getOutputObjectById` is quite expensive. There's another method `getOutputObjectsByIds` which takes a `Collection` of ids and returns `List<B>`. **But** the order of elements can be different. Though I need a way to ensure that both Lists have the same sorting at the end.

I first thought about using a `LinkedHashMap` and do something like this:

```
List<A> input = ...;
List<B> output = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> intermediate = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
for(A a : input) {
    intermediate.put(a.getId(), a);
}
for(B b : getOutputObjectsByIds(intermediate.keySet())) {
    intermediate.put(b.getId(), b);
}
for(Object o : intermediate.values()) {
    output.add((B) o);
}
```

That's so much code, copying objects around multiple collections, etc.

I really hope, there's a shorter and more elegant way to do this.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: If both lists are **linked/related** by **id** than what is the reason for sorting the list in a first place?

Comment: List<A> comes from Database A. This list is correctly ordered. It basically only gives me the IDs which I afterwards have to fetch from Database B. But Database B only supports `getOneItemById` or `getMultipleItemsByIdsInRandomOrder`. The first method is expensive/slow, though I'd like to use the second one. But when using it, the order of the returned items is not the same as in `List<A>`. At the end I have two Lists with the right results, but only List<A> has the correct sorting and I need to sort List<B>, so that `a[0].id = b[0].id ... a[n].id = b[n].id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you tagged this `java-8` so I'll offer use of streams:

```
List<A> input = ...;
HashMap<IdClass, B> bsById = new HashMap<>();
for(B b : getOutputObjectsByIds(input.stream().map(A::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()))){
    bsById.put(b.getId(), b);
}
return input.stream().map((A a)->bsById.get(a.getId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This uses an intermediate `HashMap`, to avoid a O(n^2) situation with a parallel scan over the list for each member of `input`.

Comment: Yeah, I love Java 8 `:)`. But there's something missing in your code. `map(A::getId).collect(...)` will give you `List<IdClass>` but not `B`. But generally this looks way better than my code above!

Comment: @BenjaminM Right, fixed. Am I using getOutputObjectsByIds correctly?

Comment: Yeah, you can't use it wrong. It's a fictional method. I did not want to pollute the problem with database queries, though I had to invent some more generic method name.

Comment: @fabian Whoops, fixed. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on hexafraction's work, I created a quite similar solution, which doesn't create a new `List`, but instead sorts the given `List`:

```
/*
 * converts a Collection<T> to Map<ID, T>
 * ID is specified by the keyFunction
 */
public static <T, ID> Map<ID, T> collectionToMap(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, ID> keyFunction) {
    return collection.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(keyFunction, Function.identity()));
}

/*
 * sorts List<T> to have the same ordering as List<O>
 * two functions have to be provided, that are used to get the List's ID
 */
public static <T, O, ID> void sortListByObjects(List<T> list, Function<T, ID> listIdFunction, List<O> objects, Function<O, ID> objectIdFunction) {
    Map<ID, T> map = collectionToMap(list, listIdFunction);
    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, map.get(objectIdFunction.apply(objects.get(i))));
    }
}

/*
 * abstraction of the method above, which sorts List<T> by a List of IDs
 */
public static <T, ID> void sortListByIds(List<T> list, Function<T, ID> listIdFunction, List<ID> ids) {
    sortListByObjects(list, listIdFunction, ids, Function.identity());
}
```

It's pretty simple to use:

```
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("4", "1", "9");
List<Foo> unsortedList = Arrays.asList(new Foo("1"), new Foo("9"), new Foo("4"));
sortListByIds(unsortedList, foo -> foo.getId(), ids);
```

Or:

```
List<Foo> unsortedList = Arrays.asList(new Foo("1"), new Foo("9"), new Foo("4"));
List<Bar> sortedList = Arrays.asList(new Bar("4"), new Bar("1"), new Bar("4"));
sortListByObjects(unsortedList, foo -> foo.getId(), sortedList, bar -> bar.getId());
```